# Curl alternative in c

Tags: c, http, curl, visual-studio-2017, libcurl

I posted a new question because I'm not able to comment on the link: [Getting cURL to work with Visual Studios 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878888/getting-curl-to-work-with-visual-studios-2017)
I need to set environment (particularly in Visual Studio) for http file handing.

However getting some error, tried to solve as per output error but not fruitful.
[image]

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

There are several questions asked with similar headline but installing and getting curl work really proving a trivial task.
As an alternative, I already tried with socket programming for http handling but that need manual entry of host ip address. Is there any good alternative for curl?

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: "that need manual entry of host ip address" - no, there's a few ways to do DNS e.g. [GetAddrInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfoexw). But HTTP is complicated so curl or similar is better than doing it yourself.

Comment: Judging by the screenshot you're having problems building curl yourself, not using curl. Is that correct? Can't you find a pre-built curl to use? Funnily enough curl have [a list of alternatives](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html) themselves. (I'll highlight WinInet since that's built into Windows too but haven't used it myself to recommend.)

Comment: Helpful comments... basically I'm trying to work with Microsoft Azure and trying to access file from/to blob storage on cloud. Since blob supports http, I am looking for possible options having C API.