# Getting cURL to work with Visual Studios 2017 32-bit on a 64-bit machine

Tags: c++, curl, x86, visual-studio-2017, 32bit-64bit

Running Windows 7 64-bit (Intel i5 64bit).

I remember setting up Visual Studio 2017 Community for 32-bit.

(I assumed this would give my apps backwards compatibility and also run on 64 bit machines, maybe a bad assumption?).

In any case, to confirm, the advanced linker settings are targeting x86... as well as the build configurations targeting 32bit, x86.

My app (C++ with Boost) has been compiling and running fine.

Now I am trying to add cURL but not looking so good.

**Steps Attempted to compile cURL as 32 bit:**

- c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build>vcvarsall.bat x86
- nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static MACHINE=x86

(also tried linking static C CRT with RTLIBCFG=static, no difference)

- Additional Include Directories: added path to /include dir
- Preprocessor Definitions: added CURL_STATICLIB
- Additional Library Directories: added path to /lib
- Additional Dependencies: added libcurl_a.lib

The cURL function in this sample linked:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) printf("curl_easy_init() succeeded!\n");
else fprintf(stderr, "Error calling curl_easy_init().\n");
return 0;
```

but at the very end of the compile"

```
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(720,5): error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code 1112.
```

UPDATE:
Linker Advanced Setting was not set back to x86 after trying below links, the true error is:

```
fatal error LNK1120: 60 unresolved externals
```

they all look like this but for each object file referenced:

> libcurl_a.lib(easy.obj) : error LNK2019

(FYI - I did try these and build cURL as if I were targeting x64, but the functions (in the sample code) would not resolve during linking.)

[Getting cURL to work with Visual Studios 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878888/getting-curl-to-work-with-visual-studios-2017)

[Getting LibCurl to work with Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171165/getting-libcurl-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: I just added all the curl files to a new folder in an existing project, set the include directory, and compiled. Seemed like the easiest way to deal with it.

Comment: "module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'" are you sure you are compiling your project for Win32 (aka x86)?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I - the lazy guy I am - would have used NuGet.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ)

Comment: @swordfish: Dang...I had tried to change VS to 64 and forgot the advanced linker at 64 bit...let me re-try

Comment: @paulmckenzie: went through that, however the 4 step (the most important?) is depreciated in that menu and could not find it....and really wanted to keep things 32

Comment: @Swordfish I always forget to check that for C++ things. I don't expect them to be there. Thanks for the reminder. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja Its just like with Schroedingers Cat ... you \*have\* to look. ;)

Comment: @swordfish: Ok, fatal error LNK1120: 60 unresolved externals....however it built without error as a dll (but haven't run it)...now sure why it cant resolve the cURL calls built static?

Comment: @P.S. Step 4: Project Properties -> [Tree to the left] Configuration Propertioes --> VC++ Directories --> [Right side] Include/Library Directories. Make sure you add them to all configurations you are interested in.

Comment: so either compile as a DLL if it actually runs or update VS to 64 bit?

Comment: The DLL does compile and execute correctly...was really wanting static but may have to go this route....